# How can I import a module folder from a tests folder

Tags: python

I'm working on a project with this folder structure using pytest for tests

```
project
├── example
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── example.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test_1.py
```

I'm trying to import `example.py` from `test_1.py` but every way I've tried hasn't worked.

I've tried using `sys.path.append('../)` then `import example` and just using `from ... import example` but neither of these methods has worked. `sys.path.append('../')` didn't let me import example and `from ... import example` errored with `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I've also tried using `python setup.py develop` and it let me import example, but none of the methods are imported.

This is the code that is in test_1.py. It currently imports example but it has no content.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("../example/")
import example
example.test()
```

Contents of example.py

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

The setup.py is the template from [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/setup.py/blob/master/setup.py)

Comment: Appending `'../'` is unlikely to work since no `__init__.py` exists in that directory - that is the file Python uses to know if there is a module there. Have you tried appending `../example/`?  The basic issue here is that you need both directories in your PYTHONPATH, which you could set manually when you run the program or programmatically.

Comment: I just tried this and it has the same issue where it "imports" it but it has no functions.

Comment: By 'this' do you mean you specified the `PYTHONPATH` variable in the shell you are running Python in, or changed one of your files? If the latter, you should include the code you're trying and failing with. It's impossible for us to tell if you're doing it correctly otherwise.

Comment: Im trying `sys.path.append("../example/")` then importing.

Comment: You should show us that code, so we can faithfully replicate what you're doing.

Comment: Ive been trying to recreate what has been happening but It's not reproducing what im getting. Should I post the reposotory that has the broken code because I cant reproduce it?

Comment: You should put a minimal example in the question itself. So, probably include some minimal code in `example.py`, `test_1.py` and `setup.py` that demonstrates the problem. See [this](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I updated the question to contain the code I used. I linked the setup.py because I just used a template so I linked template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the path resolution isn't functioning as you expect. In your `example.py` file do this:

```
import sys
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(f"{dir_path}/../example"))
import example
example.test()
```

Then, when in your root directory run `python tests/test_1.py`. This should execute `test()` from the example directory.

The `realpath()` function is the key here, as it will resolve the actual system path. If that isn't resolved it assumes whatever you're handing it is from the root (i.e. `/example`, which is wrong).

Comment: This works-ish. It works but as soon as I put it into a function for pytest it stops seeing `example.test`.

Comment: @Ollieeeee [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath) has a conf file that might be the better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `sys.path.append` results in flake8 reporting *E402 module level import not at the top of the file*. There are various hacks to this around which essentially depend on disabling E402; directly or by deception. There are at least two other ways.

1. Add `__init__.py` to the tests directory so that pytest loads the tests from within the parent dir and natively finds the include directory.
2. `pip install -e .` from within the parent and have the package loaded in a developer environment.

For the sake of consistency I started with uninstalling every package (so pip freeze returns nothing) and creating virtual environments for each of the approaches. I omitted the `setup.py` file favoring a minimal `pyproject.toml` file. Then `pip install pytest` and `pip install flake8` in both. For packages, the second approach then shows an additional `example` package, i.e.

```
(.venv) PS C:\xxxx\Stackoverflow\proj_hatch> pip freeze
attrs==22.1.0
colorama==0.4.5
# Editable install with no version control (example==0.0.1)
-e c:\xxxx\stackoverflow\proj_hatch
flake8==5.0.4
iniconfig==1.1.1
mccabe==0.7.0
packaging==21.3
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pycodestyle==2.9.1
pyflakes==2.5.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytest==7.1.3
tomli==2.0.1
```

The net outcome is that both approaches have a working pytest.

```
(.venv) PS C:\xxxx\Stackoverflow\proj_hatch> pytest
================ test session starts =========================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\xxxx\Stackoverflow\proj_hatch
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                    

tests\test_1.py .                                     [100%] 

=================== 1 passed in 0.01s ======================== 
(.venv) PS C:\xxxx\Stackoverflow\proj_hatch>
```

In both versions set `example/__init__.py` as below. This has an additional benefit of allowing the structure (which function in which file) to change later while keeping the import for other applications stable.

```
from example.example import test
__all__ = [
    "test",
]
```

In both versions the test is:

```
import example

def test_1():
    ex1 = example.Test()
    assert ex1.b == 2
```

With the *first* approach it is necessary to add `.\tests\__init__.py` so that pytest loads the test from within the project directory and is able to find the `example` directory. I expect this has some implications for how you write tests.

With the *second* approach I started off using hatch however it seemed to work with little more than moving the `example` directory to `src\example` and by creating a `pyproject.toml` file. I've a suspicion there is some magic in the later versions of python that help. I am using 3.10.8 for this exercise.

```
[project]
name = "example"
version = "0.0.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "path_to_your_project")
```

Comment: This has the same issue that sys.path.append has for me. it "imports" but it has no functions or anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.